# Wordpress Shortcode will not return vars inside html string

Tags: php, html, wordpress, shortcode

I've tried everything I can think of. the title spits out at the top of the content wrapper and the html tags stay where they should.

I'm performing this shortcode from a page. I need the title and perma link to an image in the media library so that I can spit out html to show it on a page via shortcode

```
add_shortcode( 'ispimg', 'isp_gallery_item' );

function isp_gallery_item( $atts ) {

// Attributes
$a = shortcode_atts( array(
    'id' => '',
), $atts );


$isp_post_id = get_post($a['id']);
setup_postdata($isp_post_id);

$pt = the_title();

return "<h3>".$pt."</h3>";


wp_reset_postdata();

}
```

Comment: first of all, your `wp_reset_postdata();` will not work. what is your error( it's unclear for )? and what you want to achieve?

Comment: return = "<h3>".$pt."</h3>"; ?? ... and same as @SamvelAleqsanyan - its unclear what you want to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure if this is your issue, but I suggest you not to mess with the main query, you may be affecting other parts of your page because of that.

Use the API functions like [`get_the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) instead:

```
function isp_gallery_item( $atts ) {
    // Attributes
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '',
    ), $atts );

    return sprintf( '<h3>%s</h3>', get_the_title( $a['id'] ) );
}
add_shortcode( 'ispimg', 'isp_gallery_item' );
```

Or in case you need the loop, take a look at the [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) class.

Comment: I need the title and perma link to an image in the media library so that I can spit out html to show it on a page via shortcode.